# Morphing particle system, interact with surface

Tags: particles

I need to recreate this animation:
[image: demo of splashed particles]

https://youtu.be/TZ3Ki3fxwS0?t=64

Is it possible to recreate these blob particles to splashy things when they interact with the surface?

if it can be done procedurally it will be the best choice for me.

Comment: While files, videos, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), besides thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.